# Addition of 2 + 2.8 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The expression `2 + 2.8` is valid in Haskell and evaluates to `4.8`
Similar to C which involves something called type promotion, Haskell uses type inference and adhoc polymorphism to get the result.

Question is whatever be the reason is it not an example of weak typing in both the languages.

Comment: As far as Haskell is concerned, the key point is that, in spite of the polymorphism, in `2 + 2.8` neither `2` nor `2.8` can possibly be specialised to an integer type. See also: [*Type signature of num to double?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21894463/2751851); [*Haskell datatype conversion problems*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5445735/2751851).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Weak typing" and "strong typing" are somewhat subjective terms, reasonable people will often disagree on exactly what they mean.

### C

In C, you have 2 which has type `int`, and 2.8 which has type `double`.  When you compute `2 + 2.8`, the "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied, which promotes the `int` to `double`.  So you get this:

```
((double) 2) + 2.8
```

This converts the 2 (an `int`) to a `double`.  The result is type `double`.

### Haskell

In Haskell, there are no implicit conversions.  What happens in Haskell is that 2 has type `Num a => a` and 2.8 has type `Fractional a => a`.  2 + 2.8 therefore has type `Fractional a => a`.

However, this is a problem because `Fractional a => a` is polymorphic.  You can think of it as a polymorphic function which takes zero arguments.  You pass in a type, and the function produces a value of that type.

So you can do this:

```
2 + 2.8 :: Rational
```

Or you can do this:

```
2 + 2.8 :: Double
```

You will get different answers.  When you write `2 + 2.8 :: Rational`, then the 2 is `Rational`, the 2.8 is `Rational`, and the whole result is `Rational`.  When you write `2 + 2.8 :: Double`, then the 2 is `Double`, the 2.8 is `Double`, and the result is `Double`.  You don't get conversions.

### Summary

You can think of it like this: in Haskell, the type checker knows that the result has type T, so the inputs have type T as well.  In C, the type checker doesn't "look ahead" like that, so it has to convert the types on an ad-hoc basis.

This is more obvious when you do things like this:

```
1 / 2 + 0.0
```

In C, this will give you 0.0, because `1 / 2` is integer division.  In Haskell, this will give you 0.5, because *everything* will be done using `Double` or `Rational` or whatever you choose.  This is a pretty major difference between Haskell and C, and it's generally the kind of thing people mean when people say "strong" or "weak" typing (that is, when they can even agree on what that means).

So in C, you get:

```
(double) ((int) 1 / (int) 2) + (double) 0.0
//       ^^^ intermediate result stays in int
```

In Haskell, you get:

```
(1 :: Double) / (2 :: Double) + (0.0 :: Double)
```

If you want the C-like behavior in Haskell, you end up with this:

```
fromIntegral (1 `quot` 2 :: Int) + 0.0 :: Double
```

Comment: Indeed:  in the interpreter, `:t (2 + 2.8)`   gives `(2 + 2.8) :: Fractional a => a`

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. Can I reason about this as follows. Addition requires two instances of Num.  while `2` is an instance of `Num` but 2.8 is instance of Fractional which has Num as superclass. So I can add these two numbers because Num is superclass of Fractional.

Comment: At best, that's an imprecise way of saying it.  I would say that addition requires *one* instance of `Num`.  That instance is a concrete type, like `Int` or `Double`.  When you add two numbers, they must both have the same type, and that type must be an instance of `Num`.  2.8 is a value which has type `Fractional a => a`.  When you add 2 + 2.8 you pick a type which is an instance of Fractional (which means it's also an instance of Num, because Num is the superclass).  I hope I'm not just confusing things further.

Comment: Or to try and explain the terms: `Num` is a class, `Int` is a type which is an instance of `Num`, and `2 :: Int` is a value which has type `Int`.  We just have to be precise when we use the words "class", "instance", "type", and "value" since they have technical meaning, at least when we're explaining things.  We're often sloppy with these terms, however, especially since "class", "instance", and "value" correspond to terms "interface", "class", and "instance" in languages like Java.

Comment: Nice example. A few years ago I was asked by a colleague to guess what `1/2*x*x+4*x+2` would evaluate to when `x=2` in C. I failed, but realized how Haskell did not have this "promotion" issue.

Answer (score 6):

`2` is polymorphically any numeric type in Haskell.  `2` is not fully polymorphic in C.

Try, instead, to be more explicit about your types in both langauges:

```
float test()
{
    int i = 2;
    float f = 2.8;
    return (f+i);
}
```

vs

```
test :: Float
test = (2 :: Int) + (2.8 :: Float)
```

What happens?

Answer (score 6):

There is no type promotion in Haskell, or else `(2::Int) + (2::Double)` would be legal. Instead, the *literal* `2` has type `Num a => a`, which means it can be treated as a *value* of any type that has an instance `Num`.

There is, however, type *defaulting* in the interactive interpreter. An expression like `show 2` (which is implicitly called if you attempt to display a simple expression like `2`) is ambiguous; the interpreter doesn't know whether to return `"2"` or `"2.0"` or some other string value that is valid for a type which is an instance of `Num`. Rather than forcing the user to specify a type via `show 2 :: Integer`, the interpreter simply selects a default type `Integer` to use for an otherwise polymorphic value.